# Bash, get 3 last files for similar name of file, by date in name of file

Tags: bash, file, sorting

**System**

```
Linux local 5.0.0-27-lowlatency #28-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 20 20:33:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Question**

Is possible get last 3 files by date (part of name of file) based on first 4 similar characters?

**Input**

```
3tpt_20190827_060911792.csv
3tpt_20190828_060912327.csv
3tpt_20190829_060911410.csv
3tpt_20190830_060912001.csv
3tpt_20190831_060911118.csv
3tpt_20190901_060911358.csv
3tpt_20190902_060911748.csv
3tpt_20190903_060911777.csv
3tpt_20190904_060911087.csv
3tpt_20190905_060913841.csv
Alco_Price_20190810_080007170.csv
Alco_Price_20190811_080006328.csv
Alco_Price_20190812_080006557.csv
Alco_Price_20190813_080007255.csv
Alco_Price_20190814_080006951.csv
Alco_Price_20190815_080006878.csv
Alco_Price_20190816_080006952.csv
Alco_Price_20190817_080007152.csv
CIP kost6_20190829_164004710.csv
CIP kost7_20190829_112005195.csv
CIP kost7_20190829_164004724.csv
CIP kost8_20190829_112005205.csv
CIP kost8_20190829_164004742.csv // for example 3. newest file for 'CIP'*
CIP kost9_20190829_112005227.csv
CIP kost9_20190829_164004753.csv // for example 2. newest file for 'CIP'*
CIP kost9_20190829_165004198.csv // for example 1. newest file for 'CIP'*
```

**Expected output**

```
3tpt_20190903_060911777.csv
3tpt_20190904_060911087.csv
3tpt_20190905_060913841.csv
Alco_Price_20190815_080006878.csv
Alco_Price_20190816_080006952.csv
Alco_Price_20190817_080007152.csv
CIP kost8_20190829_164004742.csv
CIP kost9_20190829_164004753.csv
CIP kost9_20190829_165004198.csv
```

**I tried**

```
ls | uniq -w4
```

And some combinantions with that, but it returns only one file. And how can I get (sort) files via date, which is part of file (`NAME_YYYYMMDDD_HHMMSSSSS.csv`)?

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

**Update**

Command.

```
ls > asd.txt; cut -c 1-4 asd.txt | uniq | xargs -Ifile bash -c "grep 'file' asd.txt | sort -b -t '_' -k 2,3 | tail -n 3"
```

Input.

```
3tpt_20190810_061011816.csv
3tpt_20190811_060912007.csv
3tpt_20190812_060910510.csv
3tpt_20190813_060911075.csv
3tpt_20190814_060911689.csv
3tpt_20190815_060911418.csv
3tpt_20190816_060911416.csv
3tpt_20190817_060911483.csv
3tpt_20190818_060911370.csv
3tpt_20190819_060911134.csv
3tpt_20190820_060911941.csv
3tpt_20190821_060911321.csv
3tpt_20190822_060911232.csv
3tpt_20190823_060911576.csv
3tpt_20190824_060911873.csv
3tpt_20190825_060911855.csv
3tpt_20190826_060911245.csv
3tpt_20190827_060911792.csv
3tpt_20190828_060912327.csv
3tpt_20190829_060911410.csv
3tpt_20190830_060912001.csv
3tpt_20190831_060911118.csv
3tpt_20190901_060911358.csv
3tpt_20190902_060911748.csv
3tpt_20190903_060911777.csv
3tpt_20190904_060911087.csv
3tpt_20190905_060913841.csv
Alco_Price_20190810_080007170.csv
Alco_Price_20190811_080006328.csv
Alco_Price_20190812_080006557.csv
Alco_Price_20190813_080007255.csv
Alco_Price_20190814_080006951.csv
Alco_Price_20190815_080006878.csv
Alco_Price_20190816_080006952.csv
Alco_Price_20190817_080007152.csv
Alco_Price_20190818_080006854.csv
Alco_Price_20190819_080006893.csv
Alco_Price_20190820_080006030.csv
Alco_Price_20190821_080006614.csv
Alco_Price_20190822_080008754.csv
Alco_Price_20190823_080006543.csv
Alco_Price_20190824_080007035.csv
Alco_Price_20190825_080006745.csv
Alco_Price_20190826_080006466.csv
Alco_Price_20190827_080006716.csv
Alco_Price_20190828_080006693.csv
Alco_Price_20190829_080005834.csv
Alco_Price_20190830_080006772.csv
Alco_Price_20190831_080007234.csv
Alco_Price_20190901_080008703.csv
Alco_Price_20190902_080006663.csv
Alco_Price_20190903_080007009.csv
Alco_Price_20190904_080006726.csv
Alco_Price_20190905_080006404.csv
art_info_20190813_200910412.csv
art_info_20190821_150910982.csv
art_info_20190904_200911005.csv
asd.txt
Brand_list_20190625_0510.csv
CIP1_20190812_111004332.csv
CIP1_20190813_105004414.csv
CIP1_20190814_110004061.csv
CIP1_20190814_111004562.csv
CIP1_20190814_112004539.csv
CIP1_20190814_135004807.csv
CIP1_20190815_094004023.csv
CIP1_20190903_122003816.csv
CIP 16_20190903_092004327.csv
CIP_20190812_105004438.csv
CIP_20190812_111004314.csv
CIP_20190812_113003892.csv
CIP_20190814_110004031.csv
CIP_20190815_101004603.csv
CIP_20190816_094004230.csv
CIP_20190816_153003821.csv
CIP_20190829_102004209.csv
CIP2_20190812_111004347.csv
CIP2_20190814_112004560.csv
CIP3_20190812_111004375.csv
CIP4_20190812_111004390.csv
CIP5_20190812_113003911.csv
CIP bel_20190829_171004879.csv
CIP dom_20190830_102004468.csv
CIP DT_20190904_105005222.csv
CIP k1_20190904_120004083.csv
CIP k_20190904_115003878.csv
CIP k_20190904_121004631.csv
CIP k2_20190904_121004653.csv
CIP k3_20190904_121004671.csv
CIP k4_20190904_121004687.csv
CIP k8_20190904_121004706.csv
CIP k9_20190904_121004721.csv
CIP kolesn_20190830_101004809.csv
CIP kost10_20190829_112005105.csv
CIP kost11_20190829_113004742.csv
CIP kost1_20190829_111003993.csv
CIP kost1_20190829_112005077.csv
CIP kost1_20190829_163005460.csv
CIP kost1_20190902_090004365.csv
CIP kost_20190829_102003983.csv
CIP kost_20190829_111003972.csv
CIP kost_20190829_121004075.csv
CIP kost_20190829_163005445.csv
CIP kost_20190829_165004177.csv
CIP kost_20190830_084003859.csv
CIP kost_20190830_100005953.csv
CIP kost_20190902_090004314.csv
CIP kost_20190903_175004956.csv
CIP kost2_20190829_112005124.csv
CIP kost2_20190829_163005470.csv
CIP kost 2_20190829_165004151.csv
CIP kost2_20190902_091004252.csv
CIP kost2_20190902_092004226.csv
CIP kost2_20190902_094005360.csv
CIP kost3_20190829_112005134.csv
CIP kost3_20190829_163005481.csv
CIP kost3_20190902_092004264.csv
CIP kost3_20190902_094005406.csv
CIP kost4_20190829_112005151.csv
CIP kost4_20190829_164004669.csv
CIP kost4_20190902_092004300.csv
CIP kost5_20190829_112005167.csv
CIP kost5_20190829_164004687.csv
CIP kost5_20190902_092004337.csv
CIP kost6_20190829_112005177.csv
CIP kost6_20190829_164004710.csv
CIP kost7_20190829_112005195.csv
CIP kost7_20190829_164004724.csv
CIP kost8_20190829_112005205.csv
CIP kost8_20190829_164004742.csv
CIP kost9_20190829_112005227.csv
CIP kost9_20190829_164004753.csv
CIP kost9_20190829_165004198.csv
CIP kostina10_20190903_173004267.csv
CIP kostina11_20190903_174004830.csv
CIP kostina1_20190902_171004547.csv
CIP kostina1_20190902_172004172.csv
CIP kostina1_20190902_173004618.csv
CIP kostina1_20190903_170004630.csv
CIP kostina1_20190903_173004253.csv
CIP kostina12_20190903_174004839.csv
CIP kostina12_20190903_181004437.csv
CIP kostina12_20190903_183004958.csv
CIP kostina13_20190903_174004847.csv
CIP kostina_20190902_170004568.csv
CIP kostina_20190902_171004525.csv
CIP kostina_20190903_170004605.csv
CIP kostina2_20190902_172004192.csv
CIP kostina2_20190903_173004277.csv
CIP kostina3_20190902_172004206.csv
CIP kostina3_20190903_173004286.csv
CIP kostina4_20190902_172004219.csv
CIP kostina4_20190903_173004296.csv
CIP kostina5_20190903_173004305.csv
CIP kostina6_20190902_172004237.csv
CIP kostina6_20190903_173004314.csv
CIP kostina7_20190902_172004250.csv
CIP kostina7_20190903_173004332.csv
CIP kostina8_20190903_173004350.csv
CIP kostina9_20190903_173004368.csv
CIP kostina wine1_20190903_174004713.csv
CIP kostina wine_20190903_170004583.csv
CIP kostina wine_20190903_174004681.csv
CIP kostina wine2_20190903_174004736.csv
CIP kostina wine3_20190903_174004750.csv
CIP kostina wine4_20190903_174004775.csv
CIP kostina wine5_20190903_174004795.csv
CIP kostina wine6_20190903_174004819.csv
CIP koval1_20190902_125004761.csv
CIP koval_20190902_123005017.csv
CIP koval_20190902_125004704.csv
CIP koval meat1_20190902_134004159.csv
CIP koval meat_20190902_130004218.csv
CIP koval meat_20190902_135004850.csv
CIP koval meat2_20190902_134004219.csv
CIP koval meat3_20190902_135004905.csv
CIP koval meat5_20190902_135004941.csv
CIP koval meat6_20190902_135004976.csv
CIP kozak 1_20190902_111004709.csv
CIP kozak 1_20190902_113004182.csv
CIP kozak_20190902_111004728.csv
CIP kozak_20190902_112003960.csv
CIP kozak2_20190902_113004232.csv
CIP kozak 3_20190902_113004203.csv
CIP kozak 4_20190902_113004223.csv
CIP kozak5_20190902_113004243.csv
CIP kozak6_20190902_113004252.csv
CIP meat_20190902_134004277.csv
CIP_new for XML_20190816_153003846.csv
CIPtaras1_20190903_142004791.csv
CIPtaras_20190903_133005037.csv
CIPtaras_20190903_142004747.csv
CIPtaras2_20190903_142004821.csv
CIPtaras3_20190903_143004418.csv
CIPtest_20190814_110004081.csv
CIP_test_20190904_152648516.csv
CIP_test_20190904_153613279.csv
merch_20190821_190906414.csv
Price_20190810_061241534.csv
Price_20190811_061131054.csv
Price_20190812_061136441.csv
Price_20190813_061143313.csv
Price_20190814_061140316.csv
Price_20190815_061147084.csv
Price_20190816_061155167.csv
Price_20190817_061144303.csv
Price_20190818_061140965.csv
Price_20190819_061138157.csv
Price_20190820_061142357.csv
Price_20190821_061142722.csv
Price_20190822_061152858.csv
Price_20190823_061151866.csv
Price_20190824_061202921.csv
Price_20190825_061148768.csv
Price_20190826_061146044.csv
Price_20190827_061146548.csv
Price_20190828_061202533.csv
Price_20190829_061137793.csv
Price_20190830_061149138.csv
Price_20190831_061215519.csv
Price_20190901_061142399.csv
Price_20190902_061145861.csv
Price_20190903_061146422.csv
Price_20190904_061155080.csv
Price_20190905_061141271.csv
Push_offers20190718_0510.csv
Push_offers20190802_1220.csv
Sample_lang_20190703_1230.csv
sample_lang_20190813_201731275.csv
sample_lang_20190904_200939502.csv
```

Output.

```
3tpt_20190903_060911777.csv
3tpt_20190904_060911087.csv
3tpt_20190905_060913841.csv
Alco_Price_20190903_080007009.csv
Alco_Price_20190904_080006726.csv
Alco_Price_20190905_080006404.csv
art_info_20190813_200910412.csv
art_info_20190821_150910982.csv
art_info_20190904_200911005.csv
asd.txt
Brand_list_20190625_0510.csv
CIP1_20190814_135004807.csv
CIP1_20190815_094004023.csv
CIP1_20190903_122003816.csv
CIP k4_20190904_121004687.csv
CIP k8_20190904_121004706.csv
CIP k9_20190904_121004721.csv
CIP_new for XML_20190816_153003846.csv
CIP_test_20190904_152648516.csv
CIP_test_20190904_153613279.csv
CIP2_20190812_111004347.csv
CIP2_20190814_112004560.csv
CIP3_20190812_111004375.csv
CIP4_20190812_111004390.csv
CIP5_20190812_113003911.csv
CIP k4_20190904_121004687.csv
CIP k8_20190904_121004706.csv
CIP k9_20190904_121004721.csv
CIP_new for XML_20190816_153003846.csv
CIP_test_20190904_152648516.csv
CIP_test_20190904_153613279.csv
CIPtaras1_20190903_142004791.csv
CIPtaras2_20190903_142004821.csv
CIPtaras3_20190903_143004418.csv
CIP_new for XML_20190816_153003846.csv
CIP_test_20190904_152648516.csv
CIP_test_20190904_153613279.csv
merch_20190821_190906414.csv
Alco_Price_20190903_080007009.csv
Alco_Price_20190904_080006726.csv
Alco_Price_20190905_080006404.csv
Push_offers20190718_0510.csv
Push_offers20190802_1220.csv
Sample_lang_20190703_1230.csv
sample_lang_20190813_201731275.csv
sample_lang_20190904_200939502.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a solution that creates a more robust key than `sort` can create on its own. This solution manages that with awk:

```
$ awk -F"[_.]" '{print substr($0,1,4)","$(NF-2)","$(NF-1)","$0}' yourfile |
> sort |
> awk -F, '$1!=k{for(i=1;i<=3;++i)if(a[i])print a[i];k=$1;delete a}
>    {a[1]=a[2];a[2]=a[3];a[3]=$4}
>    END{for(i=1;i<=3;++i)if(a[i])print a[i]}'
```

Explanation:

The first `awk` prepends to each line a comma-separated compound key in the order you want: `4-char,date,time,whole-line`. Then all you need is vanilla `sort`.

The first line of the 2nd `awk` detects the "change of primary key (4-char)" and prints up to the last 3 lines of the former key, stored in an array `a`.

The second line of the 2nd `awk` pushes the next line into the three-line array `a`.

The last line of the 2nd `awk` just prints out the last key group.

Here is the output I get from your 2nd, larger, input file:

```
3tpt_20190903_060911777.csv
3tpt_20190904_060911087.csv
3tpt_20190905_060913841.csv
Alco_Price_20190903_080007009.csv
Alco_Price_20190904_080006726.csv
Alco_Price_20190905_080006404.csv
art_info_20190813_200910412.csv
art_info_20190821_150910982.csv
art_info_20190904_200911005.csv
asd.txt
Brand_list_20190625_0510.csv
CIP k4_20190904_121004687.csv
CIP k8_20190904_121004706.csv
CIP k9_20190904_121004721.csv
CIP_20190829_102004209.csv
CIP_test_20190904_152648516.csv
CIP_test_20190904_153613279.csv
CIP1_20190814_135004807.csv
CIP1_20190815_094004023.csv
CIP1_20190903_122003816.csv
CIP2_20190812_111004347.csv
CIP2_20190814_112004560.csv
CIP3_20190812_111004375.csv
CIP4_20190812_111004390.csv
CIP5_20190812_113003911.csv
CIPtaras1_20190903_142004791.csv
CIPtaras2_20190903_142004821.csv
CIPtaras3_20190903_143004418.csv
merch_20190821_190906414.csv
Price_20190903_061146422.csv
Price_20190904_061155080.csv
Price_20190905_061141271.csv
Push_offers20190718_0510.csv
Push_offers20190802_1220.csv
Sample_lang_20190703_1230.csv
sample_lang_20190813_201731275.csv
sample_lang_20190904_200939502.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In case I need only `3` chars, just change `print substr($0,1,3)`, right? And if I wanna list 5 files instead 3, how can I do it? And what means this error on output? `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=asd.txt FNR=228) fatal: attempt to access field -1` Thanks.

Comment: And what about function for list reverse? So work with files instead of output above?